# Using http header value in azure function binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to read the api_key from the headers and pass it as binding expression, as show below:

```
{
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "subscriptions",
      "tableName": "subscriptions",
      "partitionKey": "{api_key}",
      "take": "50",
      "connection": "learnbindingslab1_STORAGE"
 }
```

what would the correct expression to get the `api_key` from the request headers?

Comment: You should salt and hash that API key before using it as a partition key as all your queries, logs and whatnot will now contain secrets in clear.

Comment: How about using table SDK to do this directly?

Comment: without partitionKey, I can get the whole lot of items and then filter it; but I want to do it declaratively

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use any value under `context.bindingData`, and you can access nested data with dot notation - so in this case given:

`context.bindingData =`

```json
{
  "headers": {
    "some-header": "value"
  }
}
```

You can use it as a binding expression in `Id`/`PartitionKey`/`sqlQuery` with `{headers.some-header}`.

```json
{
  "Id": "{headers.some-id}",
  "PartitionKey": "{headers.some-key}",
  "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM O WHERE O.key = {headers.some-value}"
}
```